# Can't load Entity Framework Core in Azure Function

Tags: nuget, entity-framework-core, azure-functions

I'm trying to use Entity Framework Core with a C# Azure Function, and I'm getting tons of errors with libraries. Starting from the default HTTP trigger template, I created a `project.json` file containing

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

When the package restore finishes, the compiler can no longer find the extension methods in `HttpRequestMessageExtensions`:

> 016-12-21T06:59:24.728 (9,19): error CS1929: 'HttpRequestMessage' does
>   not contain a definition for 'GetQueryNameValuePairs' and the best
>   extension method overload
>   'HttpRequestMessageExtensions.GetQueryNameValuePairs(HttpRequestMessage)'
>   requires a receiver of type 'HttpRequestMessage'

(and 3 other similar errors).

I don't really need to use those extension methods, and if I delete all code that calls them, instead I get errors about the version of `System.Net.Http`:

> Exception during runtime resolution of assembly 'System.Net.Http,
>   Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a':
>   'System.BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference assembly for
>   execution.
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoadFile(String path,
>   Evidence evidence)
>
> at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(String path)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionMetadataResolver.ResolveAssembly(String
>   assemblyName)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionAssemblyLoadContext.ResolveAssembly(String
>   name)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionAssemblyLoader.ResolveAssembly(Object
>   sender, ResolveEventArgs args)'
>
> 2016-12-21T07:00:00.522 Unable to find assembly 'System.Net.Http,
>   Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>   Are you missing a private assembly file?

When NuGet adds the EntityFrameworkCore package, it installs System.Net.Http version 4.3.0, whereas Azure Functions seems to be looking for the hardcoded version 4.1.1.

I see questions about using EF6 with Azure Functions, but I don't see anything about EF Core.

Comment: Can you share the function code or a minimal repro? Is this with the standard HTTP trigger template?

Comment: @FabioCavalcante This was with the standard C# HTTP POST trigger template.

Answer (score 0):

one solution is changing from Azure Function v2 core to Azure Function v1 framework.

Comment: Please check these 2 links:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs   and    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions